# Prove that $5^n + 2\cdot3^{n-1} + 1$ is multiple of $8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Prove that $5^n + 2\cdot3^{n-1}+ 1$ is multiple of $8$.

I've tried using induction (it isn't):

For $n=1$:

$$5^1 + 2\cdot3^{n-1} + 1 = 8$$

If it is true for $n$, then $n+1$?

\begin{align}
5^{n+1} + 2\cdot3^n + 1 
=
&(4+1)^n\cdot(4+1)+ 2\cdot(2+1)^n + 1 
\\
=& (4^n + n4^{n-1} + 1)\cdot(4+1) + 2\cdot(2^n + n2^{n-1} + 1) + 1 
\\
=
&
(4k+1)\cdot(4+1) + 2(2r+1) + 1 
\\
= &16k+4k+4 +1+4r+2+1 
\\
= 
&20k + 4r + 8 = 4(5+r+2)
\end{align}

But i've only proved it is multiple of $4$.

Comment: I don't see how you are using that it is true for n in the inductive step.  So it is n't really induction.

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? Polynomial long division? This isn't necessarily the best way to go, but it's a hammer.

Comment: If you declared what $k$ and $r$ are, say with the phrase "letting _ = _, this is _" to link the chains of equality, whatever you're arguing would be clearer, you could easily strengthen your argument by reversing the substitution if that does the trick, and correctness would be easy to analyze because it should only depend on whether equal things were replaced with each other.

Comment: @fleablood To add to that, you usually want to express the thing you claim to be a multiple of 8 in terms of the thing you assumed to be a multiple of 8, which is $5^n+2*3^{n-1}+1$. That's where polynomial long division would come in handy, if you can't figure out how to find such a relative expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove this through two separate steps:

1. $5^n \mod 8$ is 5 if $n$ is odd and 1 if $n$ is even.
2. $2 \cdot 3^{n-1} \mod 8$ is 2 if $n$ is odd and 6 if $n$ is even.

Once you have the above two statements you have then concluded that in either case of $n$ odd/even it's equivalent to 0 modulo 8.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
5(5^n+2\cdot 3^{n-1}+1)=5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^n+1+4(3^{n-1}+1)
$$

Answer (score 3):

You only need `modular arithmetic` here: both $3$ and $5$ have order $2$ modulo $8$, i.e. $3^r\equiv3^{r\mod 2},\enspace 5^r\equiv5^{r\mod 2}\pmod 8$. Now

- If $n$ is odd, $5^n\equiv 5$ and $3^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod8$, so
  $$5^n + 2*3^{n-1}+ 1\equiv 5+2+1\equiv 0\mod8.$$
- If $n$ is even, $5^n\equiv 1$ and $3^{n-1}\equiv 3\mod8$, so
  $$5^n + 2\cdot3^{n-1}+ 1\equiv 1+2\cdot 3+1\equiv 0\mod8.$$

Answer (score 2):

$5^n+2*3^{n-1}+1 = 5+2*1+1=8$ (mod n) for n coprime with 3 and 5. $n=8$ is such a number.

Comment: @pwaqo I note that my answer is the shortest of all (although perhaps too compact  since I am using Fermat's little theorem without a reference?), but I find myself at the bottom of the ladder. Then again, there is no comment that I made an error (which unfortunately happen rather often).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use induction:

$5^{n+1} + 2\cdot3^n +1 = 5^n\cdot5 + 2\cdot3^{n-1}\cdot3 + 1 = 5^n + 3^{n-1} + 1 + 4\cdot5^n + 4\cdot3^{n-1} = 8K + (4\cdot5^n + 4\cdot3^{n-1})$.

Suffices to show $4\cdot5^n + 4\cdot3^{n-1}$ is divisible by 8.  It's clearly divisible by 4.  So it suffices to show $5^n + 3^{n-1}$ is even.  Which we can do by, heh heh, induction (yes, you *can* do induction within induction).

$n = 1; 5^1 + 3^0 = 6$ Even.  Induction: $5^{n+1} + 3^n = 5^n + 3^{n-1} + (4\cdot5^n + 2\cdot3^{n-1})$  It's even.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it's true for $n\ge1$: then
$$
5^n+2\cdot3^{n-1}+1=8k
$$
for some integer $k$; in particular, $5^n=8k-2\cdot3^{n-1}-1$. Then
\begin{align}
5^{n+1}+2\cdot3^{n}+1
&=5(8k-2\cdot3^{n-1}-1)+2\cdot3^{n}+1 \\[3px]
&=40k-10\cdot 3^{n-1}-5+6\cdot 3^{n-1}+1\\[3px]
&=40k-4\cdot 3^{n-1}-4
\end{align}
Thus you just need to show $4\cdot 3^{n-1}+4$ is divisible by $8$, that is, $3^{n-1}+1$ is divisible by $2$, which is obvious for $n\ge1$, because $3$ is odd and so is any of its power (including $3^0=1$).